# Flink Cluster not starting when installed using homebrew

Tags: java, homebrew, apache-flink

I installed apache-flink using homebrew.

```
brew install apache-flink
```

Installation was successful. When tried to start the cluster using the following the command,

```
bash /usr/local/Cellar/apache-flink/1.12.0/libexec/bin/start-cluster.sh
```

I get the following output

```
Starting cluster.
Starting standalonesession daemon on host <hostname>.
Starting taskexecutor daemon on host <hostname>.
```

But the logs are throwing the following error.

FileName: flink-bigbounty-standalonesession-5-bigbounty.out

```
Error: Could not find or load main class -Xmx1073741824
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: -Xmx1073741824
```

FileName: flink-bigbounty-taskexecutor-5-bigbounty.out

```
Error: Could not find or load main class -Xmx536870902
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: -Xmx536870902
```

Tried the answers at the [Flink cluster not starting due to Could not find or load main class error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62232422/flink-cluster-not-starting-due-to-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-error), but no luck!!

Comment: have you tried `cd $FLINK_HOME && ./bin/start-cluster.sh`?

Comment: @Litchy `$FLINK_HOME` variable is not there in the environment. Ideally installing via `brew` should set it

Comment: I just mean first cd to the directory of flink then start cluster, because the start scripts read some config from the directory.

Comment: @Litchy I did the same. But no luck